# Can you externalize maven plugin configuration using composition?

Tags: maven

I want to define a plugin configuration along with dependencies in the separate project B, then attach it to other project A so I can run phases/goals from the project B from project A. Is this even possible with maven?

Comment: You can configure plugin configuration in the parent. The question is what kind of configuration do you need? Furthermore why would you like to defined dependencies along with it? You should use dependencyManagement instead of dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

You can run goals from plugins from the repository, if you give the full qualified name of the plugin, i.e.

```
groupId:artifactId:version:goal
```

If you want to use the short form, you either need to add it to your (parent) pom or to your `settings.xml`.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want to configure them externally before I do this.

Comment: Then you probably have to write your own Maven plugin.